# How to add an element to the end of a pointer list given head only?

Tags: c, list, pointers, linked-list, append

```
void add_end(node** head, node* new_node)
{
    if(*head==NULL)
    {
        *head=new_node;
        new_node->next=NULL;
    }else
    {

    }
}
```

I'm new to C and pointer operation. So if I want to add an element to the end of the list, how could I manage it? I have tried `node *temp=*head;` to save the address of head without changing it. Then `while(temp) { temp=temp->next}`. Apparently, temp only get a shallow copy. How could I implement this function. Thank you.

Comment: Invest in a piece of paper and a pencil. Start drawing a representation of a linked list on the paper to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first traverse to the end of the original list (based on last one's next is `NULL`). And then simply add it there.

Like this:

```
new_node->next = NULL;
if(*head == NULL)                // empty list
{
    *head = new_node;
}
else                            // not empty, traverse to end and add
{
    node *current = *head;
    while (current->next)       // <- traverse
    {
        current = current->next;
    }    
    current->next = new_node;   // <- add
}
```

Comment: There's a bug in the implementation: Head is not assigned when the list is empty. current is not pointing to the head it just points to the same place.